# How do I get turnstile to work in isabelle?

Tags: isabelle

I was wondering how do I get turnstile to work in Isabelle 2017. I new to the program and have been able to work some thereoms but I can't figure out how to get the turnstile symbol to work. Do I have change imports or is there something else I have to do?
 Thanks.

Comment: The turnstile symbol has no pre-defined meaning in Isabelle. There are some libraries that define some syntax using it, and you can define your own syntax using it, but I am not sure what you mean by ‘getting it to work’.

Comment: How do I define my own syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it seems like you want to define some custom syntax involving the turnstile symbol.

This is described in Sections 8.2 and 8.3 of the Isabelle/Isar reference manual (and some more advanced stuff in Sections 8.5.2 and 8.5.3). You can do *a lot* of fancy custom syntax with Isabelle: the list syntax `[1, 2, 3]` for `Cons 1 (Cons 2 (Cons 3 Nil))`, for example, is defined entirely in ‘user space’, as is the list comprehension syntax `[x + y. x ← xs, y ← ys, x ≠ y]`. These are pretty complicated.

However, in most cases, you only need a very small fragment of all that power: As outline in Section 8.2 of isar-ref, you can annotate syntax directly to constants as you define them (e.g. with `definition`, `primrec`, `fun`, `datatype`) by either using something like `infixl`, `infixr`, or `binder`, or by directly providing a mixfix syntax specification. The tricky part here is often defining the precedences so that they don't clash with other stuff.

If you get this wrong, you will get warnings (not upon defining the syntax, but upon using it) telling you that there are ambiguous parse trees and that you should perhaps try to disambiguate your syntax by providing better mixfix priorities.

For examples of how this looks in practice you can look, well, basically at any Isabelle syntax you already know by going to where it is defined and looking at the mixfix specification.

One place that comes to my mind is the `~~/src/HOL/IMP` directory, in particular the files `Hoare.thy` and `Types.thy`. They define some custom syntax, some of which even includes the turnstile symbol.